# Searching for 2 substrings in a list of strings

Tags: python, substring

I am attempting to count the instances of substring in a list, but I am confused on how I could count if a value has two different substrings in the same string in a list. This is my current program, and line 11 is where I am unsure what to do.

```
import json

FILENAME = "superbowltweets.json"

def main():
    with open(FILENAME) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    tweets = [tweet["full_text"] for tweet in data]
    rams_count = has_rams("rams", tweets)
    pats_count = has_pats("pat", tweets)
    both_count = has_both("pats rams", tweets)

def has_rams(sub_str, tweets):
    rams_count = len([s for s in tweets if sub_str in s])
    print("There are " +str(rams_count) +  " tweets about the Rams")
    return rams_count

def has_pats(sub_str, tweets):
    pats_count = len([s for s in tweets if sub_str in s])
    print("There are " +str(pats_count) + " tweets about the Patriots")
    return pats_count

def has_both(sub_str, tweets):
    both_count = len([s for s in tweets if sub_str in s])
    print("There are " + str(both_count) + " tweets that mention both")

if  __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

And here is a small snippet of the tweet list:

`["lets go rams!", "patriots suck and the rams are going to win!", "I hate tom brady", "rams should go back to saint louis"]`

I want to check if a value in the list `tweets` contains both "rams" and "pats", then assign that number to a variable. I would like to keep my current functions.

Comment: Can you do this by writing a normal `for` loop instead of a list comprehension?

Comment: Do you really need to define three nearly identical functions? Also, it is difficult to know what you expect without a sample of the data and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify **has_both** to:

```
def has_both(sub_str1, sub_str2, tweets):
    both_count = len([s for s in tweets if (sub_str1 in s) and (sub_str2 in s)])
    print("There are " + str(both_count) + " tweets that mention both")
```

Correct, should be and.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `and`, not `or`?

Comment: That would be "has either", not "has both".